# flutter animated splash screen from left to right

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I wanted to create a splash screen in flutter project, I've used [animated_splash_screen package](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_splash_screen) and the animation was done as shown in the GIF below.

[image: splash screen]

But, **I want to make the animation from left to right, I mean I want to make this image come from left to right in the splash screen.**
I tried to edit the code of the package, but I couldn't make it as I wanted.
So can I make the animation from left to right using this package or another package or in any way?

Comment: Don't know if there is a better solution. But without digging into animations you could use a PageView, insert the your splash screen and the next screen in whatever order and animate from one to other. Someone could point to more apropriated solutions but meanwhile this can sort you out easily.